# C# dictionary remove failed

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

This is in Unity.
When I try to remove an element I've added to this particular dictionnary, the remove fails and i dont understand the behaviour.

Here is the declaration :

```
private Dictionary<int, EnemyControler> remainingMobs = new Dictionary<int, EnemyControler>();
```

At some point, I do that :

```
remainingMobs.Add(newEnemy.MobID, newEnemy);
```

MobID being an int I increment every time I create a new enemy, which is attached to each of them

When the enemy dies, in his Destroy() method, he calls this :

```
public void EnemyDied(int someID) {
    if(remainingMobs.Remove(someID)) {
        print("removed "+someID);
    } else {
        print("Failed to remove " + someID);
        DisplayRemainingMobs();
    }
}
```

This is the DisplayRemainingMobs method :

```
public void DisplayRemainingMobs() {
    string availableKeys="";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, EnemyControler> pair in remainingMobs){
        availableKeys+= pair.Key + ", ";
    }
    print(remainingMobs.Keys.Count + " are available : " + availableKeys);
}
```

This is where things go wrong.
As I call the DisplayRemainingMobs() earlier, the output is :

> 2 are available : 1, 2,

Which is completely what is expected.
But then, as I kill one of the two that I've spawned, and the .remove() is called on the dictionary, the output of the print becomes :

> Failed to remove 2
>
> 0 are available :

I don't understand why the .remove() fails, nor why after it failed no more keys are available. I have tried a lot of things, including swapping the int to string thinking it may came from there. I can't get to debug this, and whatever I print only tells me it should work. The numbers match during my tests.

I have even made a full function where I use all those function on another dictionary specially made for this, to be sure, and everything goes as it should.

I have in mind that it may come from the fact that the remove is called from a method, but then how can I solve that, please ?

(cant tag dictionary apparently because of low reput)

Edit : here is the complete code :
This is the WaveControler class (the one with the most code in it)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveControler : MonoBehaviour {

public EnemyControler enemy;
public Transform spawnLocation;
private EnemyControler newEnemy;
private int waveNumber;
private Dictionary<int, EnemyControler> remainingMobs = new Dictionary<int, EnemyControler>();
private int mobID;

void Start () {
    waveNumber =2;
    mobID=0;
    Spawn();
}

void Update () {        
    if(AllEnemiesDead()) {
        print("GO TO NEXT WAVE");
        GoToNextWave();
        Spawn(); 
    } else {
        DisplayRemainingMobs();
    }
}

void  Spawn() {
    for(int i=0; i<waveNumber; i++) {
        print("Wave #"+waveNumber+" debug : i="+i);
        newEnemy = Instantiate(enemy, spawnLocation.position, spawnLocation.rotation) as EnemyControler;
        newEnemy.MobID= ++mobID;
        print("Spawning mob #" +mobID.ToString());
        remainingMobs.Add(newEnemy.MobID, newEnemy);
    }
}

public void GoToNextWave() {
    print("Wave "+waveNumber+" completed.");
    waveNumber++;
}

public void EnemyDied(int someID) {
    if(remainingMobs.Remove(someID)) {
        print("removed "+someID.ToString());
    } else {
        print("Failed to remove " + someID.ToString());
        DisplayRemainingMobs();

    }
}

public bool AllEnemiesDead() {
    print("remainingMobs.Count==0 ? " + (remainingMobs.Count==0));
    return remainingMobs.Count==0;
}

public void DisplayRemainingMobs() {
    string availableKeys="";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, EnemyControler> pair in remainingMobs){
        availableKeys+= pair.Key + ", ";
    }
    print(remainingMobs.Keys.Count + " are available : " + availableKeys);
}
```

}

And this is the class with the .Destroy()

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyControler : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody myRB;
public WaveControler wave;
public float moveSpeed;

public PlayerControler thePlayer;

public int MobID { get; set; }

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControler>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.LookAt(thePlayer.transform.position);
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    myRB.velocity = (transform.forward *moveSpeed);
}

private void OnDestroy() {
    wave.EnemyDied(MobID);
}

public override string ToString(){
    return String.Format("i'm number "+ MobID);
}
```

}

Comment: Dictionary.Remove() isn't broken. Your code is broken. Either you're removing entry 2 before you think you are, or (more likely IMO) you have multiple dictionaries and sometimes you're using the wrong one. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the issue. There is nothing in your question that is helpful in understanding whether or not all of these operations use the same actual Dictionary instance.

Comment: Can you show us the Destroy() method?

Comment: how is this class instantiated? is it attached to a game object? or are you referencing it some other way

Comment: @Weird Please put the code in the question. Pastebin links are strongly discouraged here. We don't want your entire project. We want just enough to reproduce the bug. I realize there's some effort involved in that, but in programming there is always effort.

Comment: Both classes are linked to a game object

Comment: Either give some more info on your implementation or put a try catch block inside EnemyDied (Action/Function) and share the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you never set the enemy's `wave` field to the wavecontroller object. So it tries to remove the enemy from an empty wavecontroller instead of the actual one. When you instantiate the enemy, set its wave field to `this`.

Comment: I have that set in the unity interface (where you can link game objects to public parts of the script). Can send you a screen over imgur if that's allowed here.

Comment: @Weird did you try out this answer? I'm curious if this solves your issue.

Comment: @Betweenmatt Not yet, i'm still in transportations, I'll be able to try this out in a hour

Comment: This was the solution ! added only "newEnemy.wave=this;" during the spawn method and it worked, thanks a lot dude i was on this for so much time !